# How to unit test the code so that the fields with @Value get the value what I want to set in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

When I am writing Junits for the below code the firstname and lastname are not getting populated (getting null).
I have tried to pick the value from application-test.yml but that didn't work and also the default values 'F NAME' and 'L NAME' are not getting picked.

**NOTE:** Below is just a dummy code and not the actual code which I have for my use case. It's just for illustration purposes only.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class A{
  private final String a;
  
  @Value(${name.firstname:'F NAME'})
  private String firstname;
  
  @Value(${name.lastname:'L NAME'})
  private String lastname;
 
  public iWantedToBeTested() {
    System.out.println(this.firstname); // null
    System.out.println(this.lastname);  // null
  }
}
```

How can I pass/set the values of firstname and lastname from Junit test?